# Using solr in my existing java application

Tags: solr

I need to integrate solr in my existing java application.

What are the way to use solr in existing java application?

Do we need HttpServer for embedding solr?

Will embedding solr has any performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is already a complete search server. The best way to integrate solr in your Java application is by using http resquests to an independent solr server. There are various possibilities how to do it. One is to use SolrJ.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: so i need to run solr and use Solrj to communicate to solr server?

Comment: exactly, solr is an independent server that you have to communicate with. SolrJ is the connector.